# I removed list-style but adding it back in one specific place doesn't work

Tags: css

I removed the list-style from `ul` lists with the `ul {}` code below.
I am generating the `ul` and the `li` using TinyMCE editor in ASP program.
If I create a simple HTML file with similar code, everything works as expected.

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I'm trying to add a list-style back in one specific case:

```
.htmlInput ul {
    list-style-type: square;
}
```

But the list-style doesn't show up. Why not?

Comment: Try `list-style-type: square !important;`

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant HTML code.

Comment: @cakan I'd give a downvote to your comment if I could. The latter selector has a higher specificity value than the former.

Comment: @HashemQolami How can you be sure that he defined css in that order and that he doesn't have a `list-style-type: none` somewhere else after that?

Comment: @cakan This is the point. Order is not important when a selector is strong enough to override the others!

Answer (score 3):

You problem is that your first selector sets `padding` to 0 which does not give space for the square `list-style-type` when the `list-style-position` is outside.

Either change the position or override the padding on the second selector.

Comment: Nice catch! I didn't notice the added `padding: 0`.

Comment: Thank you, I change the padding and it worked. Now my problem is that the white space between the square icon and the text is to big like    1.      Test

Answer (score 1):

We don't know the HTML structure but it appears that your second selector is trying to target a `ul` inside an element with a class of `htmlInput`.

That being the case, your selector should work **but** it's possible that the padding override has meant that the bullet is hidden from view. *The padding provides an area  on which the bullet can be displayed.*

See the various examples below and test what happens when you remove the padding that has been added back.

```css
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  ul.square {
    list-style-type: square;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .square ul {
    list-style-type: square;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="square">
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
<div class="square">
  <ul>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>55</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Alternative strategy.**

You don't need to add back the padding if you use

```
 list-style-position:inside
```

instead.

```css
 ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 ul.square {
   list-style-type: square;
   list-style-position: inside;
 }
 .square ul {
   list-style-type: square;
   list-style-position: inside;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="square">
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
<div class="square">
  <ul>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>55</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
.htmlInput ul li
     {
         list-style-type: square;
     }
```

Using more specific selectors is the key when a css rule is applied
so .htmlInput ul li has priority instead fd .htmlInput ul

Comment: What is the point of using `!important` keyword when the selector itself has a higher specificity value?

Comment: The OP wants to override declarations attached to `ul` selector. If `.htmlInput ul` doesn't do that, `.htmlInput ul li` will not, because `.htmlInput ul` is strong enough to override the former selector.

Comment: @HashemQolami you are wrong.If you give it a try you will see i am right

Comment: I am generating the ul and the li using tinymce editor in ASP program.
If I create simple HTML file with similar code everything work as expected. I tried all suggestions, no luck so far .

Comment: I'm pretty sure — Have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/59Lzq5cm/1/ as can be seen the list is affected by `.htmlInput ul`. Hence using `.htmlInput ul li` has no point here.